# How to normalize fields delimited by colon thats into a single column in informatica cloud

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I need help to normalize the field "DSC_HASH" inside a single column delimeted by colon.

Input:
[image]

Outuput:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I achieved what I needed with java transformation:

1) In java transformation I created 4 output columns: COD1_out, COD2_out, COD3_out and DSC_HASH_out

2) Then I put the following code:

```
String [] column_split;
String column_delimiter = ";";
String [] column_data;
String data_delimiter = ":" ;

Column_split = DSC_HASH.split(column_delimiter);
COD1_out = COD1;
COD2_out = COD2;
COD3_out = COD3;

for (int I =0;  i < column_split.length; i++){
    column_data = column_split[i].split(data_delimiter);
    DSC_HASH_out = column_data[0];
    generateRow();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no generic parsers or loop construct in Informatica that can take one record and output an arbitrary number of records.

There are some ways you can bypass this limitation:

- Using the Java Transformation, as you did, which is probably the easiest... if you know Java :) There may be limitations to performance or multi-threading.
- Using a Router or a Normalizer with a fixed number of output records, high enough to cover all your cases, then filter out empty records. The expressions to extract fields are a bit complex to write (an maintain).
- Using the XML Parser, but you have to convert your data to XML before, and design an XML schema. For example your first line would be changed in (on multiple lines for readability):

  ```
  <e><n>2320</n><h>-1950312402</h></e>
  <e><n>410</n><h>103682488</h></e>
  <e><n>4301</n><h>933882987</h></e>
  <e><n>110</n><h>-2069728628</h></e>
  ```
- Using SQL Transformation or Stored Procedure Transformation to use database standard or custom functions, but that would result in an SQL query for each input row, which is bad performance-wise
- Using a Custom Transformation. Does anyone want to write C++ for that ?

The Java Transformation is clearly a good solution for this situation.